# HAProxy not sending health checks to backup servers

Tags: configuration, load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

In my haproxy.cfg file, I have the following config for the backend

```
backend app
    balance     roundrobin

    server  s1 127.0.0.1:8000 check
    server  s2 135.111.29.95:80 check

    server  b1 135.111.29.96 check backup
```

Yet, when I check the HAProxy stats, no health checks are being done on the backup server.

Am I just missing some line in the configuration?

[Screencap of HAProxy backend stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7vQU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the port number for the backup server?

Comment: huh. so that was easy to fix. Thanks! If the port isn't specified, the backup still works though - do you know why it has to be done like this?

Comment: I think if the port is not specified, it defaults to the same as the incoming connection.  Because a `backend` section could be referenced by multiple `listen` sections (each listening on different ports), the port that should be checked is ambiguous.  Not 100% sure, but that's my understanding.